# SQL Server Service Broker

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

What is the replacement of SQL Server Service Broker in Microsoft Azure SQL Database?

Answer (score 0):

There is no replacement - see [this connect issue](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217321-sql-database/suggestions/423275-enable-sql-service-broker-in-sql-azure)